# Get data from gradle at runtime

Tags: android, gradle

We develop some modules and use the same connector class. Mow we use at static data. calls to server is different between the application and between develop/production.

I have some questions:

1. Is it is possible to get data from gradle at runtime?
2. Is it possible to generate/set data at variable at my classes when gradle builds the module (by use at build types) and gradle.properties?

Answer (score 5):

you can also use `buildConfigField` in your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // ...

        buildConfigField "boolean", "CHROMECAST", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "NOTIFICATION_COVER", "false"
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://your/production/url/\""
    }
    debug {
        // ...

        buildConfigField "boolean", "CHROMECAST", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "NOTIFICATION_COVER", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://your/development/url\""
    }
}
```

in your app code you can access these variables via e.g. `BuildConfig.CHROMECAST` or `BuildConfig.API_URL`

for resources you can create specific resources for your debug build in `src/debug/res` e.g. a special app icon or override the app name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `productFlavors` is exactly what you want:

To use them you have to add to you **build.gradle** in your module the code below :

```
android{
    ...
    productFlavors {
        test1 {
            applicationId "your.package.application.test1"
        }
        test2 {

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

After then you have to create folder in `src` folder with the same name as  build variants: for example for `test1` you have to create **test1 folder**.

In the next step, you have to add `res` folder to **test1** folder and for example add `values/strings.xml`

To test you can add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your app 2</string>
</resources>
```

Now when you choose test1 build variant your application will has name "Your app 2"

To change build variants you have to use tasks or you can set it in view below:

[image]

Comment: in case he only wants stuff that diffs between dev/debug and release builds product flavors are overkill.

Comment: as far I know you can configure `buildConfigField` also in productFlavors. For me productFlavors gives more possibilities. That's the reason why I propose it. :)

Comment: sure you can. but the goal of product flavors is to provide different versions of the app e.g. free vs paid or playstore vs amazon and not development vs release. while my suggestion (`buildConfigField` in the `buildTypes` makes more sense in this specific case)

Comment: Yes For this case your proposition is better